# Как заполнить Grid через привязку данных?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, разметка

Если в *Grid* помещать элементы (без определения строк и столбцов) или помещать их в одну и ту же ячейку, то элементы встают один на другой, как бы в разных слоях.

```
<Grid>
    <Border Width="20" Height="30" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
    <Border Width="30" Height="20" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Это то, что мне нужно, но я не знаю как заполнить *Grid* через *Binding*. Это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите на смысл! Если вы хотите показать список, нужно использовать `ItemsControl` или производные от него. А уж заставить `ItemsControl` показывать элементы один на другом просто.

Например, так:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Width="10" Height="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <!-- здесь ваш код -->
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```